# Creating a wav file from a blob

Tags: javascript, file, blob, wav, wit.ai

I'm using the [audio-react-recorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-react-recorder) library to record audio from a user that want to eventually send to my back-end (as a wav-file). The react-recorder is generating a blob (`{blob: Blob, url: 'blob:http://localhost:3000/c572ac68-6b7c-4992-b134-947df05ef32b', type: 'audio/wav'}`) but I am unsure on how to convert it to a `.wav` file to be sent to the back-end. What I've tried so far:

```js
let f = new File([audio], 'test.wav', { lastModified: new Date().getTime(), type: audio.type });
```

which causes an error when I try to pass to the API (wit.ai) I'm using. Also when I try to download this file, it is unplayable so I assume I'm not creating the file properly.
Any ideas how to properly create the `.wav` file from the blob?

Comment: If `audio` is the variable holding the object you are describing then your blob object is at `audio.blob` not just `audio`.

Comment: You can use a simple `fetch()` call with your blob as the request body.

Comment: thanks @PatrickEvans changing audio to audio.blob worked!